# How to integrate and Program Avatar customization in HTML(5)?

Tags: html, image

I am making a Game in HTML5. In one part of it, I want the users to be able to customize the avatar they get by default.

For sample, let me share a screenshot from Zombie Lane on Facebook (now this game may not be in HTML5 but that's not the point):

[image]

My question is as to how do I include the images in the HTML5 page and in which format?

Whenever a clothing is different shirt is selected, the change is applied immediately. Is it a whole new photo that we see, or is the photo changed somehow by programming? How is it done?

NOTE: I do not want to get into 2D/3D rendering or any complicated algorithms, what's the simplest way?

Comment: this is quite a broad question, is there anything _specific_ you are having trouble with?

Comment: @epoch I am a newbie, this is my first app, I have no idea what to do.